# How can I implement a timeout for closing a TCP connection using TcpStream in Rust?

Tags: rust, tcp

I have a function that connects to a TCP endpoint, sends a message, and then waits for two messages. After the function completes, I want to close the connection. However, I would like to add a timeout to the entire function so that if the message exchange doesn't finish within a specified time, the connection will be disconnected. What is the ideal way to achieve this in Rust with the TcpStream?

Currently, I am using the timeout function from tokio https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.timeout.html. However, it doesn't appear to be the optimal choice for my use case.

```
use std::time::Duration;

use tokio::{net::TcpStream, time::timeout};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    connect().await;
}

async fn connect() {
    let conn = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:7000").await.unwrap();

    // drop the connection within 2 seconds
    let _ = timeout(Duration::from_secs(2), do_something(conn)).await;
}
async fn do_something(conn: TcpStream) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `timeout()` is not good for your use-case?

Comment: I assume you are using [TcpStream](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html) from `tokio`?

Comment: "However, it doesn't appear to be the optimal choice for my use case". Please show a minimized version of your use case and explain what the "optimal choice" would be. If you want to do something specific, share that with us so we could talk about concrete problems.

Comment: Hello @AleksanderKrauze and, i have just added the code to the question.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman  It doesn't look like it's implemented correctly.

Comment: Why not? It certainly looks properly implemented to me.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman hmm, I thought there would be a way to achieve that from the socket level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For blocking streams, a timeout is usually set for a single connect, read or write operation. Non-blocking steams don't have an analogue at the syscall level. Using `tokio::time::timeout()` for each connect/read/write should give you roughly the same behaviour as timeouts for the corresponding blocking operations. You can also use [`tokio_io_timeout::TimeoutStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-io-timeout/latest/tokio_io_timeout/struct.TimeoutStream.html) to configure timeouts for all read and write operations.